# Compilation error while calling opencv method

Tags: c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am getting the address of an OpenCV Mat object in long. After initializing the object I want to call the following method

```
 Mat::Mat(const Mat& m, const Range* ranges)
```

[OpenCV method link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat%3a%3aMat%28const%20Mat&%20m,%20const%20Range%2a%20ranges%29)

But I am getting compilation errors. I haven't done c++ in a long time. Can anyone help?

**CODE**

```
void HelloWorld::callBack(jlong addrRgba, float dt) {

long lrgba = (long) mRgba;
Mat bgraMat = *(Mat*) lrgba;

Mat rgbMat = new Mat(&bgraMat, Range::all());   //cant get this to work
}
```

**ERROR MSG**

```
error: no matching function for call to 'cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat*, cv::Range)'
```

Comment: What does `Range::all` return? Looks like it's a `Range` and not a `const Range*`.

Comment: According to <a>http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#range</a> "The static method Range::all() returns some special variable that means “the whole sequence” or “the whole range”, just like ” : ” in Matlab or ” ... ” in Python. All the methods and functions in OpenCV that take Range support this special Range::all() value"

Comment: The error tells you what function you think you need; you are passing a pointer and a value. The docs say you *actually* need an object and a pointer.

Comment: Do this: `Mat rgbMat = Mat(bgraMat, Range::all());`

Comment: Ok. I have tried a few different ways to resolve the error but still can't get it right. Can you tell me what changes I need to make in the above code?

Comment: I couldn't find the constructor you mentioned. `MatND` has one taking `Range*`, but `Mat` doesn't.

Comment: @sgar91 I get the following error ": error: conversion from 'cv::Mat*' to non-scalar type 'cv::Mat' requested" when I use your code . Any other ideas?

Comment: @PeterWood The constructor is given in the question http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat%3a%3aMat%28const%20Mat&%20m,%20const%20Range%2a%20ranges%29

Comment: @user603125 Which version of OpenCV are you using? Those docs are for 2.1, whereas 2.4 is the most recent. The constructor you want doesn't exist in 2.1.

Comment: @user603125... Do you just want to create a copy of `bgraMat` in `rgbMat`?

Comment: @PeterWood I am using the latest one 2.4 version of OpenCV

Comment: @sgar91 yes, but using that specific constructor if possible.

Comment: @PeterWood yes, it contains the address of the Mat object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
Range rAll = Range::all() ;   
Mat *rgbMat = new Mat(bgraMat, &rAll);
```

EDIT: PK. Good that it solved the problem. Just to help you undertand why I proposed this:

You want to use the constructor:

```
 Mat::Mat(const Mat& m, const Range* ranges)
```

It take a reference to a `Mat` variable. You simple pass one `Mat` variable. And take a pointer to a `Range` variable. You can pass the adress of one `Range` variable. `Range` just store two `int`:`start` and `end`. It is copiable. One special "static" vale of `Range` is what `all()` return and what you can copy and pass in `rAll`. You will need to check that this work rigth and that not just compile.

EDIT 2: Trying to understand the meaning of what are you doing, I will propose simple:

```
Mat *rgbMat = new Mat(bgraMat);
```

or

```
Mat rgbMat = Mat(bgraMat);
```

I think it will be the same as:

```
Range rAll[2];
rAll[0]= Range::all() ;
rAll[1]= Range::all() ;
Mat *rgbMat = new Mat(bgraMat, rAll);
```

as @Peter Wood pinted.
Also I'm curios about:

```
long lrgba = (long) mRgba;
Mat bgraMat = *(Mat*) lrgba;
```

If mRgba is a pointer to the Mat you want to clone, why not?:

```
Mat *rgbMat = new Mat(*mRgba);
```

Comment: The docs say `ranges` has a range for each dimension of `Mat m`. In your case if `m` isn't one dimensional, you'll likely have problems.

Comment: Should be `Mat *rgbMat = new Mat(bgraMat, rAll);`, not `&rAll`.